# selenium: find element methods (like Click(), Sendkeys etc ) are not being shown

Tags: python, selenium

Though i have been working as manual QA but i have recently started working on automation. I am using 
selenium with Python (Visual Studio).
The problem is very basic. The problem i am facing is that whenever i try to use the webdriver.findelementbyID 
or name or even with XPath it does not show me the methods to work with like click, sendkeys, text etc etc. 
When i put a dot after findelement to access the methods it just shows me the message "no completions". 
Can anyone please help?

I have gone through the tutorial and executed the same code as the instructor did but my code is not working.

Here is my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driverFF = webdriver.Chrome()
driverFF.get("http://www.google.com/")
print(driverFF.title)
driverFF.find_element_by_name("btnK") # Here if i try to add click() or 
                                   any other method it does not 
                                   show me the method list rather shows 
                                   me the message "no completions" right 
                                   after I put a DOT (To see methods 
                                   list)
print("Executed")
```

Comment: one important point i forgot to mention here is that if i try to print the find element output on console, the programs gets executed correctly without any problem. But the problem occurs if i try to access the find element methods.

Comment: Hi @user1847090, while importing `from selenium import ` are you getting any auto completion suggestions or you are simply writing the whole line?

Comment: @user1847090 I think the problem is, your visual studio code is not recognizing/loading the selenium module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about first assigning `driverFF.find_element_by_name("btnK")` to something, i.e.

```
element = driverFF.find_element_by_name("btnK")
```

Then autocompletion may work on `element`.

---

As stated in the Troubleshootings (see *[[1](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_intellisense/)] or [[2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_troubleshooting)]*), other possible causes may be

> ***Cause: The path to the python executable is incorrect***
>   Solution: Configure the path to the python executable in the settings.json
>   Remember to re-start VS Code once done (this won’t be necessary in a future release).
>
> ***Cause: The custom module is located in a non-standard location***
>   The custom module hasn’t been installed using Pip.
>   Solution: Configure the settings.json to include this custom location for autocompletion to work
>   Remember to re-start VS Code once done (this won’t be necessary in a future release).
>
> ***Cause: VS Code was not launched from the active virtual environment***
>   The path to the custom modules is set when a virtual environment is activated.
>   Solution: Launch VS Code from a Terminal/Command window with the correct virtual environment activated

Comment: Did that too... but showed me the same message as "No completions".

Comment: yeah the restart was missing. It worked Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks. Glad to help.

Comment: Done Ticking. :)